# Assign function to variable inside function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have multiple functions that require authentication such as creating comments, liking comments and voting for different sorts of polls. However, for better UX, I am displaying a popup for registration if the user is currently not signed in and after registration, I want to execute that same function again. However, the current approach is not working and inside the `handleRegistrationSuccess` function the `stalledExecution` variable is undefined. Here is my code for better understanding:

```
...
let stalledExecution: () => Promise<void>; // save stalled functions

// Create comment
const handleCreateComment = async (comment: string) => {
    if (!user) {
        setIsRegistrationOpen(true);
        stalledExecution = () => handleCreateComment(comment);
        return;
    }

    await commentApi.createComment({
        postId,
        body: comment,
    });
    getComments();
};

// Like comment
const handleLike = async (commentId: string) => {
    if (!user) {
        setIsRegistrationOpen(true);
        stalledExecution = () => handleLike(commentId);
        return;
    }

    await likeApi.like(commentId);
};

// Registration was successfull (user variable will now be assigned to current user)
const handleRegistrationSuccess = async () => {
    setIsRegistrationOpen(false);
    await stalledExecution(); // execute original function
    stalledExecution = null; // reset
};
```

I hope this makes sense what I am trying to achieve. My guess is that `stalledExecution` is not in scope outside of the `handleCreateComment` and `handleLike` function. Alternatives/better ways to achieve this are welcome.

Comment: This looks like react - if it is, please add the tag. Where is `handleRegistrationSuccess` called, from within `setIsRegistrationOpen(true)`?

Comment: It's not really a React related question though. Yes, there is React code in the example but the question doesn't focus on that. Should it still be added? I was unsure whether to add it or not.

Comment: Either it's a react component, then the problem is clear because `stalledExecution` must be part of the component state not just a local mutable variable, or it has nothing to do with react then the example is incomplete as you haven't shown how any of these functions are called (and it actually would work if they *were* calling each other).

Comment: It is a react component but it doesn't matter if it's part of the state or not. Using the react state is only helpful for rendering purposes on the UI, not for pure JavaScript. The `handleRegistrationSuccess` function is called after the popup is closed.

Comment: Yes it does matter. You're not using pure JavaScript to call your function. With `setIsRegistrationOpen(true);`, your UI re-renders, and will call a *different* `handleRegistrationSuccess` function that has no idea about the `stalledExecution` variable from the previous render. There is no issue with the scope of the variable, there's a failure to understand how react function components work.

Comment: My bad, you are probably right! So I would wrap it into the state like so `setStalledExec(() => handleCreateComment(comment));`? It execudes right away though, thus, causing an infinite loop. How do I prevent that? Or is that even what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's the approach I mean, but look at the `useState` documentation for what passing a function to `setState` does.

Comment: Finally worked out! Thanks for the help.